# Organizing project files in Visual Studio for better explorer view

Tags: visual-studio

I have a project in visual studio where there are several files arranged in folders (filters). Inside the project, everything is well organized, but as soon as I go to the explorer, I see that all the project files are in the same folder. How can I properly organize my project so that the repository doesn't look like a bunch of files in one folder?

I use Visual Studio 2022

I tried to manually decompose the files into folders, but when I did this, visual studio began to swear that it could not find the files

Answer (score 0):

Can you share a screenshot of what you have and what you want?

I ask because there are two aspects to this.

1. The arrangement of *projects* within Solution Explorer
2. The arrangement of *files within projects* within Solution Explorer

The first can be controlled by adding solution folders. The structure is stored within the `.sln` file.

The second is generally a representation of the file system, depending upon your project type.

Also, make sure you're using the Solution Explorer view. Does this button appear clicked for you?

[image]

If so, you should unclick it. Solution Explorer can show you either the solution view (default, and what I refer to above) or the file system view.

Comment: At the moment I can see the project structure from the .sln file. I can distribute files by filters, but as soon as I go to the explorer, I see that nothing has happened in the explorer itself. I just want to organize project files for GitHub

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you see? I don't really understand what you mean unfortunately.